# Is Cloneable needed here?

Tags: java, clone, findbugs

Findbugs gives me for `public GsmSignalStrength clone()` following warning:
Class defines clone() but doesn't implement Cloneable.

Why do I have to implement Cloneable? Is it because of shallow and deep copy? I have to apologize for my bad Java skills, but I'm a Java newbie.

Here is my code:

```
class GsmSignalStrength
{
    static final byte SIGNAL_STRENGTH_UNKNOWN = 99;
    static final byte SIGNAL_STRENGTH_1 = 1;
    static final byte SIGNAL_STRENGTH_2 = 2;
    static final byte SIGNAL_STRENGTH_3 = 3;
    static final byte SIGNAL_STRENGTH_4 = 4;
    static final byte SIGNAL_STRENGTH_5 = 5;

    /* Constructors */

    GsmSignalStrength(byte signalStrength)
    {
        initClassVars(signalStrength);
    }

    GsmSignalStrength()
    {
        initClassVars(SIGNAL_STRENGTH_UNKNOWN);
    }

    GsmSignalStrength(byte[] serializedData, IntClass deserializationIndex)
    {
        initClassVars(SIGNAL_STRENGTH_UNKNOWN);
        setClassProperties(serializedData, deserializationIndex);
    }

    byte value;

    /* Methods */

    public void copyTo(GsmSignalStrength destination)
    {
        destination.value = this.value;
    }

    public GsmSignalStrength clone()
    {
        GsmSignalStrength clonedValue = new GsmSignalStrength();

        this.copyTo(clonedValue);

        return clonedValue;
    }

    private void initClassVars(byte signalStrength)
    {
        this.value = signalStrength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you write a clone() method and what do you intend to use it for?

Comment: @Maroe No it isn't. `Cloneable` contains no methods.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet you are so right. Have to read my own links!

Comment: I suggest keeping right away from `clone`. (Also, should use `@Override`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cloneable` is *not* needed here.

This is because your implementation of `clone()` does not actually clone the object. In Java, cloning specifically means using `Object.clone()`, which does JVM magic to copy the object. Although your code does something sort of equivalent to cloning (and better, IMHO - it avoids using magic), it is not true cloning.

However, [findbugs](/questions/tagged/findbugs) doesn't know that, so it's worried that you might be trying to clone a non-`Cloneable` object.

One solution here might be to rename your method to something else (`copy()`?), so it doesn't appear to be a clone.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

> A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.
>
> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the Cloneable interface results in the exception CloneNotSupportedException being thrown.

However you are not using `clone()` method in the right way. Look at this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29).

Answer (score 1):

if you implement clone as

```
public GsmSignalStrength clone()
{
    try{
    GsmSignalStrength clonedValue = (GsmSignalStrength )super.clone();

    this.copyTo(clonedValue);
    return clonedValue;
    }catch(CloneNotSupportedException e){thrown new RunTimeException(e);}

}
```

(which if you are ever going to subclass GsmSignalStrength you are going to need to be according to the documention of [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29))

the super.clone call will throw a CloneNotSupportedException

Comment: Do I need to make the class implement Cloneable or not? According to the documentation I have to do so. Furthermore I have to check for the CloneNotSupportedException exception. I would have seen the error earlier...

Comment: if you implement the clone like I did then yes, otherwise no not really but you run the risk of subclasses implementing their own clone like I did and running in a `ClassCastException`